# В 1960-х — 1980-х годах / 1960 — 1980-х годах

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Вокально-инструментальный ансамбль, или ВИА, — официальное наименование признанных государством профессиональных и самодеятельных музыкальных групп в Советском Союзе в 1960-х — 1980-х годах / 1960 — 1980-х годах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у обеих чисел нужно наращение, а эти числа соединяет тире, то после первого числа наращение не требуется:

***1960 — 1980-х годах***.

«Грамота»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом фото пробелов **нет**, но, как я понял, пробелы теперь нужны. И [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95), и [Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) думают, что нужно писать с пробелами.

Приходим к варианту без повторëнного наращения и с пробелами.

Чтобы было понятно, что наращение не нужно повторять, можно привести пример из справочника Розенталя: *5 — 7-кратное*.

Как видите, наращение не повторяется.